# mysql exclude records and display as diffrent head

Tags: mysql

I have a data table with column city and state,

```
   City      State 
   Delhi     Delhi
   Dwarka     Delhi
   Mumbai    Maharashtra
   Ahmadabad Gujarat
   Nasik     Maharashtra
   Lucknow   UP
```

Now this is the query but this will return state wise count list

```
SELECT DISTINCT reg_dealer.state,count(*) Count FROM reg_dealer GROUP BY reg_dealer.state order by count(*) desc
```

I want Mumbai City to be Displayed as ROM(Rest of Maharashtra) and other city comes under Maharashtra as Like Below

```
   State       Count 
   Delhi       2
   ROM         1
   Gujarat     1
   Maharashtra 1 
   UP          1
```

Comment: probably u can not set value on selected data u may try to php code

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN reg_dealer.state = 'Mumbai' THEN 'ROM' 
          ELSE reg_dealer.state 
       END AS state,
       count(*) Count 
FROM reg_dealer 
GROUP BY reg_dealer.state 
order by count(*) desc,
         CASE WHEN reg_dealer.state = 'Mumbai' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         reg_dealer.state
```

Comment: i mean if found mumbai as city then it will display as ROM

Comment: Sir, script run successfully but the think mumbai is a city not a state, so expected result is if city is other than mumbai then state is automatically convert into ROM else other will remain the same, as my question table say we have 2 entries from maharastra and out of which one city is mumbai and other is nasik so output should be ROM 1 , Maharashtra 1